# SQL: Left Join & not found linking

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

Is there any chance to do a LEFT JOIN in multiple tables, and if none found -> use another column to try join on this another column?

Like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main` (
  `brand` varchar(200),
  `article` varchar(200),
  `price` float,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article`)
);
INSERT INTO `main` (`brand`, `article`, `price`) VALUES
  ('brand1', '001', '10'),
  ('brand2', '002', '20'),
  ('brand3', '003', '30');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dealer1` (
  `brand` varchar(200),
  `article` varchar(200),
  `articleFixed` varchar(200),
  `price` float,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article`)
);
INSERT INTO `dealer1` (`brand`, `article`, `articleFixed`, `price`) VALUES
  ('brand1', '01', '001', '12'),
  ('brand3', '03', '003', '28');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dealer2` (
  `brand` varchar(200),
  `article` varchar(200),
  `articleFixed` varchar(200),
  `price` float,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article`)
);
INSERT INTO `dealer2` (`brand`, `article`, `articleFixed`, `price`) VALUES
  ('brand2', '02', '002', '8'),
  ('brand3', '03', '003', '38');
```

Here I'm comparing base prices with dealers. For this I use LEFT JOIN.

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `main` M
LEFT JOIN `dealer1` D1 ON M.article = D1.article
LEFT JOIN `dealer2` D2 ON M.article = D2.article;
```

but for sure, join won't work, as '01' != '001'

for this purpose I have another column, called `articleFixed`

and my **main question** is:

How to try re-join failed rows, based on another column (ps: I can have something around 10 tables with 100k rows in them)? Is it possible to do somehow? In production data is totally different, and first it should look by article column, only after that -> by articleFixed, if none join found. Also I can't use Like.

As a `result` I'm expecting to get:

```
brand  | article | priceMain | priceDealer1 | priceDealer2
brand1 | 001     | 10        | 12           | NULL
brand2 | 002     | 20        | NULL         | 8
brand3 | 003     | 30        | 28           | 38
```

Also I'm providing a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bf496/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE statement in the ON clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM main M
LEFT JOIN dealer1 D1 
ON M.article = CASE WHEN M.article = D1.article THEN D1.article ELSE D1.articleFixed END
LEFT JOIN dealer2 D2 
ON M.article = CASE WHEN M.article = D2.article THEN D2.article ELSE D2.articleFixed END
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bf496/5/0).

Comment: would it work for another column, like article | articleFixed | articleFixed2 ?

Comment: This joins to article and if there is no match then tries articleFixed. What do you mean by *another column*?

Comment: for example if I got really crazy and introduce one more column, called articleFixedByAnotherMethod, and chain would be like: try to join by article, if none -> try join by articleFixed, if none -> try join by articleFixedByAnotherMethod

Comment: This will need more WHEN statements inside the existing CASE statement. It would work but the code would become more complicated.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. Btw, can you give me an idea, how can I select only price columns in result set for dealer tables?

Comment: Change to: `select m.*, d1.price, d2.price from...`

Comment: sorry... not sure if it's possible, but I'll ask you (just yes/no). Is it possible to create an additional column, that will indicate that Join was found via articleFixed column?

Comment: You will have to repeat the CASE statement in the select list: `select m.*, d1.price, d2.price, CASE WHEN M.article = D1.article THEN 'from article' ELSE 'from articleFixed' END as fromColumn...`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT M.*, D1.price, D2.price
FROM `main` M LEFT JOIN 
     dealer1 D1
     ON M.article = D1.articleFixed LEFT JOIN
     dealer2 D2
     ON M.article = D2.articleFixed ;
```

Comment: no unfortunately, first it should try to find on column I've provided